# Sending data from android app to a PHP page using HTTP post method

Tags: php, android

I am new to android development. I am trying out a basic app. My requirement is that I need to send data from a text box in an android app to a PHP page that is hosted on net using POST method. I have browsed many sites for tutorial on this method, but didn't find a right one. Can anyone please provide me an example code for sending data from ONE textbox in an android app to a PHP page using post method? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourinput);
    input.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = input.getText().toString();
            new UploadTask().execute(text);
        }
    });
}

private class UploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://yourwebsite.com/commit.php");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs
                    .add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", params[0]));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            if (response != null) {
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                String responseContent = inputStreamToString(in);

                return responseContent;
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (progressDialog != null) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        // process the result
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

        // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        // Read response until the end
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
            total.append(line); 
        }

        // Return full string
        return total.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick comment about the inputStreamToString. You can actually avoid this with:    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF8");

Comment: Just saw the full comment. Cannot test it atm but might edit it into my answer then :) thank you

Comment: Jup sorry, I tried to linebreak and it sent my comment too early.